# Where do I store internal state?

Tags: elm

I have a record where two fields should be `0` when the record is initialized, and only updated by the internal functions.

How can I accomplish this? Where do I keep internal state? Ask the user to please supply `0` as the arguments and not touch those fields?

Comment: ```foldp``` might be what your looking for. And ```mergeMany``` to combine multiple event sources into 1 event source that you can fold over producing a behaviour representing your internal state. I'd provide some links but the documentation site is not loading for me at the moment.

Comment: @clinux I'm using the latest version of Elm. Is `foldp` still around after 0.17? Also, I have no idea how it would help.

Comment: Right, @FilipHaglund, `foldp` and `mergeMany` have nothing to do with the question. I'm not sure what @clinux is getting at.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question. Disregard my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the types and functions a module exposes by using the `exposing` keyword on the module. However, you cannot hide individual fields of a record type. Let's first define the record alias that you want to keep private:

```elm
type alias InternalModel =
    { foo : Int
    , bar : Int
    }
```

First off, we need a way to hide the internals of a value. This is typically done by exposing a type but no constructors.

```elm
module MyModule exposing (Model)

type Model = Model InternalModel
```

The above code will not let external modules see or interact with the `InternalModel` type parameter at all. You can't even create a `Model` outside of this module. This is where we can define a function that creates a new `Model` and sets those initial values to zero. You will also have to adjust the module `exposing` list (here I'll let the external module set `bar` on creation, while defaulting `foo` to zero):

```elm
module MyModule exposing (Model, newModel)

newModel : Int -> Model
newModel bar =
    Model { foo = 0, bar = bar }
```

If you want to expose "getters" and "setters" for fields, you can do so like this:

```elm
module MyModule exposing (Model, newModel, getFoo, setFoo)

getFoo : Model -> Int
getFoo (Model {foo}) =
    foo

setFoo : Int -> Model -> Model
setFoo foo (Model model) =
    Model { model | foo = foo }
```

Comment: How would you add a field with a generic type in the record? e.g. `Dict Int valueType`?

Comment: `type Model a = Model (InternalModel a)` and `type alias InternalModel a = { foo : Int, bar : a }` will let you pass in a type parameter.

Comment: Sure, but how do I pass it to the `newModel` function without passing a value of that type?

Comment: You can't really have a fully generic function like this `newModel : Int -> Model a` in Elm, because if you're returning a value of `Model a`, you have to give it something to initialize it in the body of the function, and without knowing `a`, you can't give the value anything meaningful during construction. There may be alternatives if you actually need to do something like this, but that's probably a better fit for a new question because SO starts yelling when these comment threads get too long.

Comment: One of my fields is `Dict Int a`. The default is an empty dict, so no instance of `a` is needed. Is this possible in Elm?

Comment: Ok, yes, that is possible, my bad: `newModel : Int -> Model a`, `newModel foo = Model { foo = foo, bar = Dict.empty }`. [Here's a snippet that I tested with](http://www.elmfiddle.io/view/ciucnicth00039itv1osefjga). Is that kind of thing what you're after?

Comment: Perfect; that's exactly what I needed :)